# Is there a term that describes the (immediate) loss of mass at the center of a gravitationally bound system?

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I'm curious if there is a general term in physics that describes the (immediate) loss of mass at the center of a gravitationally bound system?

For instance, if (as contrived as it may be) the Sun were to just disappear, evaporate, or otherwise be removed from where it currently resides, all the bodies that orbit it would be cast off into space, no longer locked into an orbit. Is there any kind of technical term for an event like this?

E.g.

> An _____ event describes the loss of mass which anchors/anchored a series of bodies in orbit.

I suspect no such term exists, perhaps due to the fact that such events aren't common (or realistically possible?) However, maybe there's a more technical term used for the purposes of simulation, or maybe just a colloquial term? I have little to no experience in celestial mechanics and my searches thus far haven't turned up anything.

I'd really appreciate any insight that could be provided here. If this isn't the correct forum for this question just let me know and I'll remove this question and redirect it immediately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This does happen in reality. Imagine two stars orbiting each other, but then one explodes, and the mass flies away at supernova speeds, leaving the companion all alone. There are some specific ways to describe this scenario, including "disruption" of the orbit, "ejection" of the "runaway" star which has received a "kick." Some would describe it as a "slingshot" effect and others might refer to Blaauw 1961 who first proposed this effect to explain how runaway stars could be formed. This isn't a general dynamics term but I hope adds some insight!

I'm not an expert so I'll provide a few example sources that I googled.

https://www.eso.org/public/news/eso9702/

https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/497/4/5344/5892580